# Angular with nested scopes, tried using $parent but watch still not updating

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope

I have two controls, a radio control and a checklist control, with only one of them showing at any given time (based off of a boolean `multiline`).

I also have some logic watching `$scope`.  Both of these controls are inside the same controller, so they share the same scope.  Problem is, only the `radio` element ever procs the `watch` statement!  I can't for my life get the stupid `checklist` element to proc it... and it should, because `campaignValues` is definitely updating with new values!

What am I doing wrong?  I've tried multiple `$parent` modifiers on the `.checkbox` classes, but they don't seem to do anything.  **How can I wire up the `campaignValues` param to the `watchCollection` statement?**

### Markup

```
<div class="radio" ng-repeat="campaign in campaigns" ng-if="!multiline">
  <input type="radio" name="name" 
         ng-model="$parent.$parent.campaignValue" 
         id="name_{{campaign}}" value="{{campaign}}"/>
  <label for="name_{{campaign}}">
    {{campaign}}
  </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="campaign in campaigns" ng-if="multiline">
  <input type="checkbox" name="name" 
         ng-checked="campaignValues.indexOf(campaign) != -1" 
         ng-click="toggleCheck(campaign)" id="name_{{campaign}}" 
         value="{{campaign}}"/>
  <label for="name_{{campaign}}">
    {{campaign}}
  </label>
</div>
```

### Controller

```
  // Initiate other module radio control
  // Hard-coded in - remember to change
  $scope.campaigns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];
  $scope.campaignValue = $scope.campaigns[0];

  // Initiate module checkbox control
  $scope.campaignValues = [];

  // Logic for handling when a checkbox is toggled
  $scope.toggleCheck = function(campaign) {
    if ($scope.campaignValues.indexOf(campaign) === -1) {
      $scope.campaignValues.push(campaign);
    } else {
      $scope.campaignValues.splice($scope.campaignValues.indexOf(campaign), 1)
    }
  };

$scope.$watchCollection(
  '[optionValue, campaignValue, campaignValues, multiline]', 
  function() {
    updateDashboard();
  });
```

Comment: classic issue of trying to pass a primitive into child scope...  always use objects. Or,  in other words....`ng-model` should always have a `dot` in it

Comment: Oh I think I see now.  I'll see if it fixes it.

Comment: this should help   https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Comment: I actually think you might be reading my question wrong.  I'm not having trouble with the radio module, but the checkbox one.  I followed your instructions, and while my code is better, it didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a `$watchCollection` if your models are objects, not primitives. Lots of angulars default directives, like ng-bind or {{}}, already have a `$watch` statement built in. If your using just default directives, and you 'dot' the models, its possible to build a app with out writing one `$watch` statement.

I'm assuming if your calling `updateDashboard()`, your dashboard is already marked up with loads of `{{}}`.

Working demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/AzhmeA?p=preview

Note: I've dropped the ng-if, & added double binding to show changes in the campaign models.

**app.js**

Two changes in the JS, array to object, & path to slice object.

```
// Changed array to object
$scope.campaigns = {obj: {data:['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']} };
// changed to object path
$scope.campaignValue = $scope.campaigns.obj.data[0];

// Initiate module checkbox control
$scope.campaignValues = [];

// Logic for handling when a checkbox is toggled
$scope.toggleCheck = function(campaign) {
    if ($scope.campaignValues.indexOf(campaign) === -1) {
        $scope.campaignValues.push(campaign);
    } else {
        $scope.campaignValues.splice($scope.campaignValues.indexOf(campaign), 1)
    }
};
```

**HTML**

Three changes in the HTML, both ng-repeat models changed to object path, and 2nd $parent dropped to get campaignValue model updating.

```
// changed campaigns model to object path
<div class="radio" ng-repeat="campaign in campaigns.obj.data">

// dropped 2nd $parent to get double bindings working
<input type="radio" name="name" 
         ng-model="$parent.campaignValue"
         id="name_{{campaign}}" 
         value="{{campaign}}"/>

  <label for="name_{{campaign}}">
    {{campaign}}
  </label>

</div>

<br>
campaignValue:{{campaignValue}}
<br>
campaignValues:{{campaignValues}}
<br><br>

// changed campains model to object path
<div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="campaign in campaigns.obj.data">

  <input type="checkbox" name="name" 
         ng-checked="campaignValues.indexOf(campaigns) != -1" 
         ng-click="toggleCheck(campaign)" id="name_{{campaign}}" 
         value="{{campaign}}"/>

  <label for="name_{{campaign}}">
    {{campaign}}
  </label>

</div>
```